# Can't bind to 'ngForOf' since it isn't a known property of 'div' while accessing *ngFor in child module's component

Tags: angular, ngfor, angular-module

I have imported BrowserModule in AppModule and CommonModule in child module(HomeModule). Also I am using *ngFor"" in my child module component's templete. But its showing error that Can't bind to 'ngForOf' since it isn't a known property of 'div'.

Parent Module(AppModule)

```html
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { HomeModule } from './modules/home/home.module';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { HeaderComponent } from './header/header.component';
import { FooterComponent } from './footer/footer.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    HeaderComponent,
    FooterComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    HomeModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

ChildModule(HomeModule)

```html
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { HomeRoutingModule } from './home-routing.module';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
import { CarouselModule } from 'ngx-bootstrap/carousel';

import { HomeComponent } from './home.component';
import { InspirationComponent } from './inspiration/inspiration.component';
import { AboutUsComponent } from './about-us/about-us.component';
import { BrsmComponent } from './inspiration/brsm/brsm.component';
import { PrabhupadaComponent } from './inspiration/prabhupada/prabhupada.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    HomeComponent,
    InspirationComponent,
    PrabhupadaComponent,
    BrsmComponent,
    AboutUsComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    HomeRoutingModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    CarouselModule.forRoot()
  ]
})
export class HomeModule { }
```

Comment: Can you please post the whole error message?

Comment: While compiling there is no error but while accessing the template page in which I have used *ngFor in an element is not running and this error can't bind to ngForOf since it is not a known property of div showing in console. Please let me know if u need templete file

Comment: I need the whole error message from console

Comment: you need to either use *ngFor or ngForOf. the first is syntatic sugar for the latter. source https://angular.io/api/common/NgForOf#description

Comment: Can you post the HTML, since it could be something wrong with how you're using `*ngFor`?

Comment: do you forget the "let"? *ngFor="**let** variable of array"

Comment: All the syntax were correct. I didn't understand how it worked but I restarted my IDE (VS Code) and recompiled and it worked like a charm.